# Sending symfony ChatMessage in différents channels

Tags: symfony, chatbot, slack-api

I defined an slack application added to several chanel. I want to send differents notifications in differents channels depending on the application context.

How can i do it using the symfony defaut notifier (https://symfony.com/doc/current/notifier.html#chat-channel) ?

How to use différents chat channels in symfony5 ?

- There is only one SLACK_DSN parameter.
- There is no function in ChatMessage like setChannel($myChannel).

Must i develop my own service ?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

I have my own response using the slackoption class.

```
$message->options((new SlackOptions())
        ->channel('myChannel')
```

Comment: `channel` is now deprecated since Symfony 5.1. But you can use `recipient` instead :)